# Creating instance in CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift3

I'm using swift and I have a problem with CoreData. 
What I'm trying to achieve is to create textfields(the number is up to the user) and store them in core data, and show this results at a second view. Is this possible?
I had a tip that I can make an entity for textfields and create and store instance and of this entry whenever a new textfield is created but how can I do this?

My app basically goes like, 
firstView -> tableView -> secondView
and at the firstView user can add as much textfield they want. And I want to save the text of these made textfields and show it on the tableView. And when the user selects the cell it calls the secondView which basically the detail view and it needs to have the same number of textfields as the firstView. Is this possible?

Thank you vary much.

Comment: Basically don't save instances of UI elements in Core Data. Save the relevant properties /  parameters and create the UI elements dynamically according to the parameters.

Comment: Thank you very much :)  But sorry how can I do this? I've been researching but I don't know how to do this :(  It will be very helpful if you can tell me how to do this

Answer (score 0):

What you need is called a segue. In iOS, CoreData is used to stored some data that can be reused after user shut down the app. So in your case, if you just want your table view to display the user inputs in the first view, simply use a segue. You can then pass data in this prepare for segue method.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destinationViewController = segue.destination as? YourTableViewController {

        destinationViewController.texts = self.texts
        //...
    }
}
```

Say you have 10 text fields and you want to store texts in them into Core Data. You need to first get all the texts and put them into an array of String. In future, when you get your array of string out, you will know how many text fields are there by doing a count on the array.

To save an array into CoreData, you must first convert the array into `Data` because CoreData cannot take the array type. So the code to convert to NSData and then save to CoreData will be

```
let appDelegate =
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Device", inManagedObjectContext:managedContext)
let device = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(array)
device.setValue(data, forKey: "dataOfArray")
do {
    try managedContext.save()
    devices.append(device)
} catch let error as NSError  {
    print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
}
```

When you want to get the data out and convert back into array

```
let appDelegate =
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Device")

do {
    let results = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
    if results.count != 0 {
        for result in results {
                let data = result.valueForKey("dataOfArray") as! NSData
                let unarchiveObject = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data)
                let arrayObject = unarchiveObject as AnyObject! as! [[String: String]]
                let array = arrayObject
        }
    }
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
}
```

Comment: Yes I know this. But I don't know how to save data to care data that doesn't have a attributes. Because the user can make as much textfields they want I don't know how to save it when i can't set up the attributes. Or can I ? I know i can set the attributes and save the data there cuz I've used core data multiple times. but can I do that with unlimited number of textfields? How do I do that?

Comment: @dropscar Gocha, one last question. Do you have to use core data? Code to read and write array to core data is like 50 lines. If you can use UserDefaults, it only needs 1 line to write and one line to read

Comment: unfortunately I do :( It's my project I'm doing and it needs to be in CoreData. Thank you very much and hope you have a solution :(

Comment: @dropscar Updated my answer

Comment: Thank you vary much for such a fast reply! I'll try this soon as possible! Thank you so much !! :)

Comment: I tried this and I can't do this. Maybe because I'm using Swift3 but it gives me an error saying "Can not invoke 'value' with an argument list of type '(String)'." Am I making a mistake? And with this code I cannot imagine saving 10 texts. Maybe because this is a sample code and only shows me one value? I hope maybe you can help me again. Thank you and sorry for bothering you :(